# Custom function to the power button (ubuntu 16.04)?

Tags: ubuntu, power-management, kiosk

I develop a software, which is going to be run in the kiosk mode on ubuntu 16.04. For some reasons, the computer will not be shutdown very often, so I'd like to allow for restarting only the application. To this end I wrote a bash script that kills the running instance and run it again. Because the application could freeze, I'd like it to be restarted after pushing the power button.

So far, I have tried to modify the /etc/acpi/events/powerbtn file as follows:

action=/path/to/my/script.sh

The application turns off, so the script runs, but it is not restarted (if I call the script from the terminal, it is). The second issue is, that the shutdown menu still appears.

Is it possible to set the power button in such a way, that it does a completely arbitrary thing?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Nobody knows? ;(